# Using Webpack in Express.js project to bundle Bootstrap installed with npm

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, npm, webpack

Rough structure of my project:

```
project
|-- node_modules
|   |-- bootstrap
|   |-- jquery
|   |-- popper.js
|
|-- dist
|
|-- public
|   |-- js
|   |   |-- scripts.js
|   |
|   |-- css
|       |-- styles.css
|
|-- views
|   |-- index.ejs
|
|-- app.js
```

I need to include `bootstrap` and my own `public` folder contents in my `index.ejs`. If it comes to bootstrap, I could do it using `CDN` but I want to specifically use `Webpack` to bundle everything I might need into one file in `dist`, and make sure it gets included in my `index.ejs` file - either automatically (I know webpack has this function) or just make sure `bundle.js` exists in `dist` and refer to it in `<link>` or `<script>` tags in my `index.ejs`.

I want to make sure, everything gets bundled - I don't want to have inline scripts or styles in my `index.ejs`.

I'll appreciate any help, as I couldn't find a guide or any advice, on how to achieve that. I guess the main question here is - how should I structure `webpack.config.js`?

`app.js` is my entry file, it includes following code:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRoutes);

app.listen(port);
```

current content of `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app.js'),
  },
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

Comment: What does your current webpack config look like?

Comment: @MattOestreich I've edited the question to include it above

Comment: Webpack should already be doing what you are wanting. How are you including bootstrap in your html/ejs files?